# Control JavaFx scene from another scene /Sending information To a previous scene

Tags: javafx, controller, scene

So i have a Javafx programme that contains 2 scenes

- one contains a **TableView** with th columns (ID,Product,Date) and a **Button** ("add Pruduct).
- the other one contains a some **textFields** for filling the table and a **Button** ("Save).

when i click on the *Add Product* **Button** it shows me the form

--so what i want is this : How can i update the TabelView after Clicking Save on the other scene
Meaning **Sending the information to the previous scene** and updating the tableView

Comment: Providing the problem-causing code snippets is one of the crucial actions on this page to enable others to help you.

Comment: You probably should use `Stage.showAndWait()` which waits for the window to be closed. This allows you to retrieve the info from the new window after the user is done with it...The save button would simply set some field to allow you to check, if the window was closed "regularly" and then hide the window...

Comment: Thank u very Much fabian that was exactly what i was looking for. Cuz i had a function called `UpdateTable()` i waned to execute it after i was done with the form now i can since it executs after the closing.